# Retrieve all rows with same minimum value for a column with sqldf

Tags: r, sqldf

I have to retrieve IDs for employees who have completed the minimum number of jobs. There are multiple employees who have completed 1 job. My current sqldf query retrieves only 1 row of data, while there are multiple employee IDs who have completed just 1 job. Why does it stop at the first minimum value? And how do I fetch all rows with the minimum value in a column? Here is a data sample:

```
ID  TaskCOunt
1    74
2    53
3    10
4     5
5     1
6     1
7     1
```

The code I have used:

```
sqldf("select id, min(taskcount) as Jobscompleted
       from (select id,count(id) as taskcount 
            from MyData
            where id is not null 
            group by id order by id)")
```

Output is

```
ID   leastcount
5     1
```

While what I want is all the rows with minimum jobs completed.

```
ID  Jobscompleted
5     1
6     1 
7     1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`min(...)` always returns one row in SQL as do all SQL aggregate functions.  Try this instead:

```
sqldf("select ID, TaskCount TasksCompleted from MyData 
       where TaskCount = (select min(TaskCount) from MyData)")
```

giving:

```
   ID TasksCompleted
1  5              1
2  6              1
3  7              1
```

**Note:**  The input in reproducible form is:

```
Lines <- "
ID  TaskCount
1    74
2    53
3    10
4     5
5     1
6     1
7     1"
MyData <- read.table(text = Lines, header = TRUE)
```

Comment: ... and changing the column name would be done with `sqldf("SELECT ID, TaskCount AS JobsCompleted FROM MyData  WHERE TaskCount = (SELECT MIN(TaskCount) FROM MyData)")`

Comment: This works. Thank you! But can you explain to me why? My query only retrieved one row, I believe I am missing an important subquery concept.

Comment: As stated in the answer `min` always returns a single row.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck So when you use - 

 where taskcount = (select min(..)  

how is it different from just select min (..)

Comment: Yes, that subselect always returns one row.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck can you tell me what kind subquery is your statement? So I can study on it. As in single row, multiple row, correlated subquery?

Comment: Try googling for `sql subquery`.  Also `sql aggregate`.  Or try `sqlite` or `h2` in place of `sql`.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to `sqldf`, you could use `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(ID=1:7, TaskCount=c(74, 53, 10, 5, 1, 1, 1))

dt[TaskCount==min(TaskCount)]

##    ID TaskCount
## 1:  5         1
## 2:  6         1
## 3:  7         1
```